# Recreate scope bar of UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, scope, uisearchbar, quartz-2d, uicontrol

I want to recreate the scope bar of a UISearchBar, just for use as tabs. I'd like to adopt the UISearchBar scope bar's style.

I've thought about Quartz 2D to draw these tabs in combination with UIControl for managing the different states of the tabs.

What are you thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may certainly do this using Quartz 2D and handling the related events. However, you may want to take a look at three20 ready made tabs, they may suit your needs. Download the code from

```
http://github.com/facebook/three20
```

and take a look at the TTCatalog example.